# Django URL to User's Posts

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a *Member Model* and a *Blog Model*. My blog model is called *MyPosts*. And *MyPosts user* field is FK to *Member*. 
To view a detail page of a user I have got the url type below:

```
url(r'member-detail/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$', views.MemberDetailView.as_view(), name='member-detail'),
```

And for blog posts I have the following:

```
url(r'my-posts/$',views.postlistall.as_view(), name='my-posts'),
```

Now, how can I arrange *my-posts url* to view a user's posts?

I mean, the url for a member detail view is: http : //127.0.0.1:8000/directory/member-detail/12/michael/

However my post link is: http : //127.0.0.1:8000/directory/my-posts/

How can I convert it into http : //127.0.0.1:8000/directory/12/michael/my-posts/  or something like this which might be the best?

Plus, They have two different views and templates. How can I show the last 5 posts of the user on his/her detail page. I fail in combining the 2 views.

**UPDATE UPON REQUEST**

My Models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='members')
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    member_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    member_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    member_spoken_language = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True) 
etc..

     def __str__(self):
        return self.member_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('memberships:dashboard')

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.member_name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Member.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save()
```

MyPosts model:

```
class MyPosts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True, related_name='postcreator')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=240,)
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publishing_date', 'id']
```

My Views:

```
class MemberDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Member
    template_name = 'directory/member-detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Member.objects.all()

class postlistall(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'directory/my-posts.html'  
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyPosts.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
```

Comment: Please add the code of your models an the views. The data is handled by the views, not the urls.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I thought my problem was only about the url lines. I have added more details now upon your request. Thanks.